# Subquery with incorrect syntax still returns result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Came across this by accident the other day while trouble-shooting a query, I have a basic SELECT statement that has a WHERE  IN () statement.
Now the subquery on its own is trying to select a field from a table where the field does not exist. If you run the sub-query on its own you get 'Incorrect syntax near ' which you would expect, if you run the entire query it executes and returns results. Can anyone explain how this executes because to me it makes no sense at all.

So two basic tables

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    FieldA int
    , FieldB int
)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    FIeldC int
    , fieldD int
)

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES (1,1)
,(1,2)
,(1,3)

INSERT INTO Table2
VALUES (2,1)
,(2,2)
,(2,3)
```

Now this query will fail: (which makes sense there is no FieldA in Table2)

```
SELECT FIeldA FROM Table2
```

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'FIeldA'.

Yet somehow this query will not fail, executes and returns results

```
SELECT * FROM TAble1
WHERE FieldA IN (SELECT FIeldA FROM Table2)
```

It returned all the records from Table1

Changing it to this

```
SELECT * FROM TAble1
WHERE FieldB IN (SELECT FIeldA FROM Table2)
```

returned only the first result from Table1

Tried this on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) as well as Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1)

Comment: case sensitive server?

Comment: This is by design; use proper table and column aliases everywhere and it won't happen. See [Connect #302281](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/302281), [Connect #735178](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/735178/), [Connect #772612](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/772612/), [Connect #265772](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265772/), [KB #298674](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298674), [Correlated Subqueries (MSDN)](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

SELECT *
FROM   TAble1 t1
WHERE  t1.FieldA IN (SELECT t2.FIeldA
                     FROM   Table2 t2)